# Set NTP not to receive time from peers on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ntp

In my `/etc/ntp.conf`, it says

```
By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
```

I'd like to only receive time from the specified servers to prevent DDoS attacks like [this](http://blog.cloudflare.com/technical-details-behind-a-400gbps-ntp-amplification-ddos-attack).

How can this file be modified so that time is not received from peers?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server is publicly accessible, you should have this line in your configuration:

```
restrict default kod limited nomodify noquery nopeer notrap
```

If you need remote management functions you can add `restrict` lines after that allowing particular IPs access. If it's not publicly accessible then you don't need to worry about the 'monlist' amplification attack.

You really should not be running a public NTP server if you don't know what you're doing. The management functions this line blocks, and which are exploited in the attack you linked to, have nothing to do with exchanging time with other systems. Also, "peers" different from "clients" and "servers" in NTP.

**Edit:**
The above just disables all admin functionality (which is the only thing that is known to be exploitable). NTP will not synchronize against anything unless it's specifically told to do so (via a `server`, `peer`, `broadcast`, or `manycastclient` directive - or a S0 hardware clock).

By default NTP will serve client requests, acting as a server - to disable this add `noserve` to the restrict statement above. This particular option allows you to allow some management functions while disallowing clients to synchronize time.

Alternately, if you want NTP to not "listen" to anything you can add this line instead:

```
restrict default ignore
```

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Correct, that will put it in a "unmanaged client-only" mode.

Comment: You can't use `ntpq` on an "**unmanaged** client-only" ntpd. Blocking the port at the firewall works, so long as an attacker doesn't find another way onto your system.

Answer (score -2):

You should specifically list the servers you want to listen to:

```
server 192.168.1.10
```

make sure broadcast is commented out.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to share with peers?  Do you not trust them?  You could also turn on authentication so that you can be sure the server is really them.

Comment: Then cryptographic authentication is probably the way to go.

Comment: http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#S-CONFIG-ADV-AUTH

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this isn't what he's actually asking for.

Comment: Actually the link explains how to set up authenticated NTP, which would solve his problem as revised by the comment thread.